# Getting System.NullReferenceException error when viewing various pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, error-message

I just tried accessing https://drupal.stackexchange.com/admin, and I got the following error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at ASP._Page_Views_Shared_UserInfo_cshtml.<_PostDateDefault>b__1(TextWriter __razor_helper_writer) in c:\sites\stackexchange-network\Views\Shared\UserInfo.cshtml:line 49 at ASP._Page_Views_Shared_UserInfo_cshtml.b__2(TextWriter __razor_helper_writer) in c:\sites\stackexchange-network\Views\Shared\UserInfo.cshtml:line 95 at ASP._Page_Views_Shared_UserInfo_cshtml.Execute() in c:\sites\stackexchange-network\Views\Shared\UserInfo.cshtml:line 125 at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) at StackOverflow.Controllers.StackOverflowController.RenderPartialRazorViewToString(Controller controller, String viewName, Object model) in c:\TeamCity\BuildAgent\work\af6c756150208ff6\StackOverflow\Controllers\ControllerBase.cs:line 919

[image: screenshot]

Occurs on many other pages across the sites as well.

Comment: yes, i heard they got hacked

Comment: Looks like this will get thrown anywhere that uses the `UserInfo` partial. I noticed it on "Responses" as well.

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов - No, just a buggy build got deployed.  Literally nothing but a missing `if(Post != null)`, but an awfully important one.

Comment: @KevinMontrose if I had to guess, I'd say this had to do with the logic on whether or not to display a `user-action-time` div. Am I right?

Comment: @KevinMontrose or at least get the data for it

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt - calculating the time delta for it, yeah.

Comment: Lol, there are quite a lot of information about SO that is shown there.

Comment: @nhahtdh yeah, now *everyone* will know that SO has a view called `UserInfo` that has at least 125 lines. Quick, somebody rename it!

Comment: @KevinMontrose what, do I not get a "debugger" badge or something? A job, maybe? :P

Comment: @KevinMontrose that's exactly what i would say if i got hacked ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ugh, what a day.

Another bug in view conversion, this one touched a lot of pages (basically anywhere we show a user card *without* a single Post associated). A fix is rolling out.

Comment: Not trying to criticize, but there is **always** a better alternative to displaying a stack trace on an exception in a release environment. I'm very surprised to see this on a site as esteemed as SO.

Comment: Though I guess due to the nature of the site, maybe it isn't such a bad thing.

Comment: @Phillip - you're right, it's complete crap as it dodges all our error logging too.  I'm checking in a fix for that with a vengeance.

Comment: So, reports of being hacked are greatly exaggerated?  Could someone put out a meta post (WE WERE NOT HACKED ON AUGUST 29th 2012)?

Comment: @PeterTurner this doesn't in any way smell like the result of any kind of attack. What would it be, SQL injection? Couldn't be, since we see user cards elsewhere on the site. SO databases aren't going to have duplicate data, so if SQL injection were the case they'd be gone everywhere. Not that SO would be vulnerable to SQL injection in the first place. This is pretty clearly a logic error.

Comment: Beat's me, I was just checking out meta, as I am wont to do after seeing weird errors, and saw "yeah, I heard they got hacked" after the wordpress fiasco, it would be good to know from the Devs.  Some of us can't smell .NET as well as others :)

Comment: On a programming Q&A I don't expect people to go: "Hallup!!! 1337 hackxorz!?!?! OMGWTFBBQ" when there is some error message somewhere... @PeterTurner

Comment: @PeeHaa well... umm [christianity.SE] is not a programming Q&A site. In any event, that was the first thing I saw when I came and looked here to report the bug.

Comment: In that case it wasn't a hacker, but a higher being.

Comment: [More fun with stack traces](http://i.imgur.com/UdaXb.png) -- from the "top users in this tag" page.